# How do you share local npm packages with other teams in a single repo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

## Scenario

Consider the following folder structure:

```
/my-service
  /src
  /bin
  /other-package
    /src
    package.json
  package.json
```

There are 2 npm packages: one for `my-service` and one for `other-package`.

`my-service` depends on `other-package`.

`my-service` is owned by team `A` and `other-package` is owned by team `B`.

Keep in mind team `B` will still need to deploy `my-service` when `other-package` changes. This is why we are considering a shared repository.

## Question

How do you structure this dependency such that the developer experience for both teams is reasonable?

Ideally, team `B` only needs to install and build `other-package` and can do everything they need to in that directory.

Likewise, team `A` should be able to use the latest version of `other-package` with minimal friction in local development.

## Options

I am presently considering 2 options to solve this but do not know if there are better options out there.

### Local file dependency

In this option, `my-service` has a `package.json` that looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "other-package": "./other-package"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build:other-package && npm run build",
    "build:other-package": "cd other-package && npm i && npm run build && cd .."
  }
```

### Local tarball dependency

In this option, `my-service` has a `package.json` that looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "other-package": "./other-package/other-package-0.0.1.tgz"
  }
```

In this case, team `B` needs to be responsible to run `npm pack` in the `other-package` directory when a new version is ready, update the `package.json` in `my-service` and commit that to git.

Answer (score 2):

Put both packages into separate repositories, and in the `package.json` file of the first one put a dependency to the git repository of the second one. This looks like the following:

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-other-package": "git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish"
}
```

For details on the available syntax options, see the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies).

This way both teams can work on their packages individually, and independent of each other. At the same time it is possible to refer to the package via its git url, and you can even pin a specific branch, tag or commit by providing its `commit-ish`.

In case you use GitHub for managing your git repositories, you can also use a shortcut syntax:

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-other-package": "user/project#commit-ish"
}
```

This also works for private repositories, but only for GitHub. In case of another git hosting solution, you need to use the syntax mentioned above.

Since you mentioned that the dependent team wants to use the latest version without too much friction, you might simply want to use something such as `#master` as commit-ish. Then on each `npm install` you get the latest version that is committed to the master branch.

Please note that this leads to non-reproducible builds, as you can't deterministically predict what will be installed. From my personal experience I'd rather recommend to pin your dependencies to a specific commit. While this is more work in maintenance, it leads to reproducable and predictable installs, which IMHO is worth a lot, but YMMV.

A big advantage of this approach is that both teams don't have to care about each other with respect to publishing or things like that, as you can depend on a package from the outside, without the team managing a package even knowing that someone else is using it.

If, for whatever reason, it absolutely necessarily *HAS* to be a single repository, and you can't use the approach I described, you might be interested in the term "monorepo". This basically is the concept of having a single (mono) repository for multiple packages. One tool to manage such a monorepo is [Lerna](https://lernajs.io/), and you might want to have a closer look at it.

Comment: Keep in mind team `B` will still need to deploy `my-service` when `other-package` changes. This is why we are considering a shared repository.

Answer (score -1):

> Those long divided shall be united; those long united shall be divided.

Recently I helped my team to transit to monorepo, merging 10+ repos into one. Monorepo has some downside, it puts pressure on version control facilities when it gets really big (like Google's). On the other hand, it facilitates code sharing, reuse build scripts, ci flows, batch op on git history and files, etc.

Typical monorepo approach treats subprojects equally.

```
/monorepo
  /node_modules <-- shared top level node_modules
  /packages
    /my-service
    /other-package
```

If not for particular reason, I suggest you keep both packages as siblings, instead of parent-child.

When done building either one, say other-package for example, you symlink the its dir into the top level `node_modules` dir.

```
# in /monorepo
ln -s packages/other-package node_modules
```

If you're willing to try out tool like `lerna.js`, it helps you do above chore.

Now you can specify your `my-service/package.json` like normal

```
  "dependencies": {
    "other-package": "latest"
  }
```